# Repeater Onitemcommand won't fire when binded with DataPager. Why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm working with displaying video thumbnails in the repeater control with datapager.
I recently discovered that the onitemcommand of the repeater control won't fire once
it is being bind with the datapager but if you remove the datapager from binding
the repeater it works.But I want to use the datapager for the repeater cause I want to
set the pagesize in order to display specific number of thumbnails on the repeater.
How do I make the onitemcommand of the repeater to fire using with datapager?How do I do this in asp.net? Pls help...Thankz.

Directive:

```
<%@ Register Assembly ="DataPagerRepeater" Namespace ="DataPagerRepeater" TagPrefix ="vid"  %>
```

Here's my HTML source tag of the repeater control with DataPager:

```
<vid:DataPagerRepeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" 
                        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" onitemcommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand">

                   <HeaderTemplate >
                   <table border ="0" style ="width :350px;" >
                   </HeaderTemplate>

                   <ItemTemplate >
                   <tr>
                   <td style ="border :0px; height :100px; width :350px">
                   <asp:ImageButton ID ="thumb" runat ="server"  style=" margin-right :5px" Width ="120px" Height ="75px" ImageAlign = "Left"  ImageUrl='<%#Eval("Filename","~/Thumbs/{0}") %>' />
                   <asp:Label ID="title" runat ="server"  Text ='<%#Eval("Title") %>' />
                   <br />
                   <asp:Label ID ="artist" runat ="server"  Text ='<%#Eval("Artist") %>' />
                   <br />
                    <asp:Label ID ="view" runat ="server"   Text ='<%#Eval("Views") %> '  />
                  <asp:Label ID ="Label3" runat ="server" Text =" Views" /> 
                    <br />
                   <%--  <asp:Label ID ="fname" runat ="server"  Text ='<%#Eval("VidFname") %>' /> --%>
                   <asp:TextBox ID ="fname" runat ="server"  Text ='<%#Eval("VidFname") %>' />
                     </td>

                      </tr>

                   </ItemTemplate>

                   <%--  
                   <AlternatingItemTemplate >
                   <tr>
                   <td style ="border :0px; height :100px; width :140px">
                    <asp:ImageButton ID ="thumb2" runat ="server" style=" margin-right :5px" Width ="120px" Height ="75px" ImageAlign ="Left" ImageUrl ='<%#Eval("Filename","~/Thumbs/{0}") %>' />
                   <asp:Label ID="title2" runat ="server" Text ='<%#Eval("Title") %>' />
                   <asp:Label ID ="artist2" runat ="server"  style="margin-left :20px" Text ='<%#Eval("Artist") %>' />
                   <asp:Label ID ="view2" runat ="server"  style="margin-left :20px" Text ='<%#Eval("Views") %> ' />
                  <!-- <asp:Label ID ="Label4" runat ="server" Text =" Views" /> -->

                   </td>

                      </tr>

                   </AlternatingItemTemplate>
                  --%>

                   <SeparatorTemplate >
                   <br />
                   </SeparatorTemplate>
                   <FooterTemplate >
                   </table>
                   </FooterTemplate>

</vid:DataPagerRepeater>


<asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" runat="server" PagedControlID="Repeater1" PageSize="10">
                   <Fields>

          <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Link" ShowFirstPageButton="True" ShowNextPageButton="False" ShowPreviousPageButton="False" />

          <asp:NumericPagerField />

          <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Link" ShowLastPageButton="True" ShowNextPageButton="False" ShowPreviousPageButton="False" />

                 </Fields> 
        </asp:DataPager>
```

Comment: Why did you add asp.net-mvc and asp-classic tag? It looks like asp.net webforms.

Comment: @afzullah...sorry can u transfer it to asp.net webforms plz...thanks

Comment: DataPagerRepeater is a custom control... hard to guess how it works.

Comment: Can u pls give me a sample article that demonstrate using datapager on repeater control. Thanks. I just want to make the onitemcommand works on repeater when the imagebutton is click..Thanks for any help

Comment: Here's one:[Extend Repeater to support DataPager](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/45163/Extend-Repeater-to-support-DataPager)

Comment: @afzalluh...thanks but thats what I'm using now which the onitemcommand of the repeater control is not firing. do u have any other article about this scenario?

Comment: No, but I will look at this code to see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It is working indeed! Add a Linkbutton to fire the ItemCommand:

```
<ItemTemplate >
    <tr>
        <td style ="border :0px; height :100px; width :350px">
        <asp:ImageButton ID ="thumb" runat ="server"  style=" margin-right :5px" Width ="120px" Height ="75px" ImageAlign = "Left"  ImageUrl='<%#Eval("Filename","~/Thumbs/{0}") %>' />
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server"
                            CommandName="cmd"
                            CommandArgument='<%# Eval("VidFname") %>' Text="TEST" />
```

And test in the code:

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "cmd")
    {
        //set a break point in the next line
        string myString = e.CommandName;
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Image buttons are like command button and they do fire their own OnCommand instead of repeater's OnItemCommand, so they will not fire repeater's OnItemCommand. Instead use link button with Image on it:

```
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server"
                        CommandName="cmd"
                        CommandArgument='<%# Eval("VidFname") %>' >
            <img src="test.jpg" alt="my cmd" />TEST
    </asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: Will it work if I dont use linkbutton? I just want the user to hit the imagebutton instead of linkbutton.

Comment: ImagButton is like asp button, they have their own OnCommand event. You can add image to linkbutton to look like image button. Please see my update.